# How do I install my app for internal testing release on Android TV?

Tags: google-play-console, android-tv, google-play-internal-testing

I had already followed all the necessary steps to rollout a release for internal test in Play Console. However, to install the app, I have to click on the link given by Play Console. The issue is, I cannot copy the link into the tv, let alone click it.

By using search bar, I've tried search for the app name and package name. None of them works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The link for internal testing is an opt-in link. You can opt-in from your computer's browser as long as it's logged into the same account that the Android TV is logged into. You will then be able to find the app in the Play Store on the browser. There will be an option to install it to your Android TV from the browser.

Comment: Did you find answer, i need to do that also